# Facebook share URL is not calling with query paramaters

Tags: facebook, facebook-share

A facebook share url for my site is for eg:

`www.mysite.com?q=123`

However, facebook is not calling the url with query parameters i.e `?q=123` is missing.

Is there a way to make facebook to use query parameters

Comment: other social media call the link with right query parameters - ( whatsapp too)

Comment: What is the real URL? Debug using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was meta tag `og:title` was assigned to "`name`" instead of "`property`".

Strangely, this *somehow* made facebook to ignore query parameters in URL.

Assigning meta tags to "`property`" made it work.